# IF NOT statement in Python

Tags: python

Can someone explain the if not and continue part in this code? (`hb_content` is a list of heartbeat values)

```
for index in range(len(hb_content)):
    if not hb_content[index]:
        continue
```

Comment: In this case `continue` is pointless. So I think there is some additional code you do not show us?

Comment: `not` is just an operator applied to the value of `hb_content[index]`; it is not part of the `if` statement.

Answer (score 2):

if `hb_content[index]` is a false-y value (e.g. `False`, `None`, the empty string, or anything else that isn't considered true in an `if` statement), then the loop will skip to its next iteration immediately.